# What is stopping my JS from getting my URL Hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to add a class on an element, after hyperlinking from a separate page. I have my link on `page1` set up like this:

`<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/mv7nneu4/2#redbox">go to redbox</a>`

and on `page2` I am running this function:

```
$(function() {
    var id = window.location.hash;
    $(id).addClass('expanded');
});
```

This is the div it should be affecting:

```
<div id="redbox" class="red">
  hajkldjfs
</div>
```

Which, should be grabbing the hash, then adding the class `expanded` to that element. However the class never gets appended and the console has no errors.

Here are 2 JS fiddle links I created to simulate this:

**[page1](https://jsfiddle.net/o695vhhk/2/)**

**[page2](https://jsfiddle.net/mv7nneu4/2/)**

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Seems to work for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: jsFiddle puts results in iframe.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I'm on chrome46, but I am also opening the link in a new tab, if that makes a difference

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it's not against the rules to link to JSFiddle.

Comment: No, but it *is* in the SO FAQ that questions should be able to stand on their own.

Comment: You are correct. Luckily, that's not what I was saying. The code must be in the question itself *in addition* to the link to JSFiddle.

Comment: It is all there, You can recreate the problem with the code I supplied. A link, then the function.

Comment: you should try to debug this quite a bit more. add in a console.log(id) after you grab the hash.  see if it's what you expect.  I'm guessing that it's only 'redbox' and not '#redbox' so a jquery selector isn't going to work without adding '#' + id in the selector

Comment: @bryan60 yup that was it. I think it's because jsfiddle automatically ended the url with `/` so it was treating `#redbox` as a directory, rather than a hash. I loaded the `page2` in a **[codepen](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/ZLeMJp#redbox)** and it works now.

Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: No, it's because the window location is "https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/"

Comment: ok cool. i added it as an answer, would appreciate marking it

Comment: **jsfiddle** does not use the 'normal' `window.location.has` as you see it in the browser, because the code runs in an **IFRAME** 
(as stated by @AdamAzad) (so has a different url as stated by @DaveNewton).  So you cannot "simulate this" via jsfiddle.   I recommend you simply remove the jsfiddle links to remove confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. change to

```
$('#' + id).addClass('expanded');
```

Comment: The specific issue is that `window.location.hash` does not include the `#` so `url#redbox` gives `redbox` not `#redbox`.